# Debian 12 al iniciar sesion abre siempre el navegador firefox

Tags: bash, debian, firefox, scripting

He instalado Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) en mi computadora, y desde el primer inicio de sesión se abre de forma automática el navegador Firefox. Es molesto porque suelo usar Chrome y no lo necesito abierto al iniciar. No cambié nada en la configuración de la distro, la instalé de forma gráfica y con la imagen completa (no la imagen mínima), la que no necesita conexión a Internet, Aún así la instalé con cable ethernet conectado.

**Primero:** Intenté desinstalar el navegador para evitar su inicio, con la instrucción:

`sudo apt-get --purge remove firefox`

Me devolvió la terminal una respuesta satisfactoria de la desinstalación:

*Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho

Creando árbol de dependencias... Hecho

Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho

El paquete «firefox» no está instalado, no se eliminará
0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 0 no actualizados.*

**Segundo:** Con la ayuda del programa *xfce4-session - Preferences* intenté que se ejecutara un script al iniciar mi sesión en debian.

Creé un script llamado *mata-firefox-script.sh* y lo agregué al inicio automático de aplicaciones de la aplicación *xfce4-session - Preferences*. El script lo creé y le dí permisos de ejecución en estas 2 líneas:

`touch mata-firefox-script.sh`
`chmod +x mata-firefox-script.sh`

El contenido del script fue:

`#!/bin/sh`
`sleep 10`
`pkill firefox`
`exit`

Retrasé 10 segundos la ejecución del *pkill* en el script (*sleep 10*) para dar tiempo a que se abriera el navegador desde el inicio (también probé con más segundo por si era poco) y así poder matar el proceso con *pkill*, pero mi computadora tarda menos de 10 segundos desde que inicia sesión hasta que se ve operativo el escritorio, (¡mejor dicho *Firefox*!) de modo que el script se debería de haber ejecutado con *Firefox* ya iniciado.

Al añadir el script (aplicación) al programa *xfce4-session - Preferences* (*Sesión e inicio* tiene como título la ventana de la aplicación), en el campo "*orden*" puse lo siguiente:

`cd /;./mata-firefox-script.sh`

**Por último** seguí el consejo de esta url: https://www.bonaval.com/kb/sistemas/debian/ejecutar-un-script-al-arrancar-linux-debian, de modo que usé el mismo script con el permiso de ejecución ya concedido, para copiarlo en */etc/init.d*:

`sudo cp mata-firefox-script.sh /etc/init.d`

Y lo hice daemon:

`sudo update-rc.d mata-firefox-script.sh defaults`

Pero tampoco me funcionó.

También probé con una solución que da *Firefox* directamente en su [página](https://support.mozilla.org/es/kb/firefox-se-inicia-automaticamente-al-iniciar-windows):

*En la barra de direcciones, escribe about:config y pulsa Enter.*
*Puede aparecer una página de advertencia. Para continuar, haz clic en Aceptar los riesgos y continuar*.
*Busca la preferencia toolkit.winRegisterApplicationRestart y haz doble clic en ella para establecer su valor como false.*

Pero tampoco me ha funcionado.

No se me ocurren más cosas aparte de cerrar el navegador firefox cada vez que inicie sesión en mi Debian...

¡Un saludo!
¡Y gracias por leer!

Answer (score 1):

Conseguí que Firefox no se inicie al comienzo de sesión en mi Debian 12:

Decidí buscar las ubicaciones de archivos y directorios de Firefox para eliminar todos los restos de la aplicación de Mozilla (firefox - firefox-esr) y así que no se ejecute. He buscado las ubicaciones con los comandos *whereis* y *find* desde la terminal de linux:

`whereis firefox-esr`
`sudo find / -iname firefox`

Eliminé uno por uno esos ficheros y sus respectivos directorios, teniendo mucho cuidado de no eliminar nada que perjudique al sistema operativo.

Lo hice con estos comandos, también por terminal de Linux:
por ejemplo, para eliminar */etc/firefox-esr* usé:

`rm -r /etc/firefox-esr`

Y así con el resto de ubicaciones de archivos de Firefox...

Si necesitas permiso para eliminar alguno de ellos recuerda usar sudo o su:

por ejemplo:

`sudo rm -r /etc/firefox-esr`

Luego solo he tenido que volver a instalar Firefox en Debian y todo funciona correctamente, abro Firefox cuando lo necesito y no cuando inicio el sistema.

Espero que os sirva.